# How to sort one array and use the order to sort a second array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Suppose i have two arrays
a=[4 3 6 1 7 8]
b=[3 5 1 8 4 6]

I need to sort b in the same order as a, which will be sorted in ascending order
ie.,

first sorting a
a=[1 3 4 6 7 8]
whose corresponding indices will be [4 2 1 3 5 6]
and using this indices, i have to sort b, ie.,
b=[8 5 3 1 4 6]

how do i do this in MATLAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the 2nd output of sort

```
[sortedArray,sortedIndex] = sort(a)
b(sortedIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second output of `sort` describes the ordering of the elements. See `doc sort`

```
[aSrt, ind] = sort(a);
bSrt = b(ind);
```